# How to dereference a double void pointer to an int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, indirection

I have a code that looks somewhat like this:

```
int num = 5;
int *ptr = &num;
void **xptr = &ptr;
printf ("values:%d\n",**(int *)xptr);
```

Why can't i de-reference a void double pointer,which points to an int pointer ? The below two 
examples work.

Snippet:1

```
int *ptr = &num;
int **xptr = &ptr;
printf ("values:%d\n",**xptr);
```

Snippet 2:

```
void *ptr = &num;
printf ("values:%d\n",*(int *)ptr);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void **` is not a generic pointer unlike `void *`. Any `void **` value you play with must be the address of an actual `void *` value somewhere. Compiler should raise a warning for `void **xptr = &ptr;`:

```
[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

You can do it as follows

```
int num = 5;
void *ptr = &num;
void **xptr = &ptr;
printf ("values:%d\n", *((int *)*xptr));
```

For more detailed explanation, read [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 4.9](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html).

Comment: ,yes it did generate a warning for void **xptr = &ptr.Thanks for pointing out that void ** value must be an address of a void *,instead of an address of int or char. 

`voidPointer.c:6:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     void **xptr = &ptr;`

Comment: Thanks for that FAQ,Q4.9 really answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use both asterics on both sides.

```
printf ("values:%d\n",**(int **)xptr);
```

Why? Because otherwise you give the compiler false information about what you are really doing. C-style casts can be forced to compile everything, but you must aware yourself: if you force the compiler to do something, then don't blame him to produce probably crash-code.

I'd wonder if the compiler didn't generate a warning on that. Did it and you ignored the warning?

Keep in mind that your initialization is probably wrong for the `xptr`. Please see post from haccks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25748989/1433564).

Comment: My downvote.  `void **xptr = &ptr;` makes no sense in the OP's code snippet. Suggesting `printf ("values:%d\n", **(int **)xptr);` is wrong.

Comment: This solution is not wrong if I'm correct. Just his initialization to get the ``xptr`` might be wrong.

Comment: Then you should correct that otherwise it will be considered wrong.